# WPF c# Zoom using Matrix.ScaleAtPrepend

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming

Hi I am building a drawing program and need to zoom into different parts of the drawing according to mouse position.  I am using ScaleAtPrepend and RenderTransform to achieve this.  All works great when the mouse is not moved between MouseWheel events, and then (of course) the drawing does not scale back to its original position.

I am working on a solution to store the last Point when zooming took place, and use that to preserve mouse position, but it is getting messy.
Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Here is my event handler:

```
        drawing.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(zoom);
        void zoom(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            Matrix m = drawing.RenderTransform.Value;
            Point p = e.GetPosition(drawing);
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                m.ScaleAtPrepend(1.1, 1.1, p.X, p.Y);
            }
            else
            {
                m.ScaleAtPrepend(1 / 1.1, 1 / 1.1, p.X, p.Y);
            }
            drawing.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);

        }
```

Comment: It's difficult to distinguish "zoom" from "zoom back", in either direction. You'll probably have to use a fixed center point that is set once (by e.g. some other mouse event) and kept until reset to some other value. Or implement a "reset zoom" feature by `drawing.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform();` or `((MatrixTransform)drawing.RenderTransform).Matrix = new Matrix();`. As a note, setting the Matrix of the existing MatrixTransform should be more efficient than creating a new MatrixTransform each time.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on a solution to store a 'history' of mouse positions in a push/pop array.  If mouse position has changed between zoom in and zoom out, I use the previous value for zoom out.  Fiddly though!  Thanks for that last note.